# Parameters such that the matrix is diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
k & 2 &0 \\
 m& n & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $k, m, n \in \mathbb{R}$ find the values of $k, m, n $ such that the matrix is diagonizable.

**Solution**

The eigenvalues of $A$ are the solutions of the equation:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1-\ell & 0 &0 \\
 k& 2-\ell &0 \\
 m& n &1-\ell
\end{vmatrix}=0 \Leftrightarrow  \left ( 1-\ell \right )^2 \left ( 2-\ell \right )=0 $$

meaning that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\ell_1=1$ (double) and $\ell_2=2$ (simple).

In order the matrix to be diagonizable we must have that $\dim \mathcal{V}(1)=2$. Also from the equation of the dimension and rank we have:

$$\dim \mathcal{V}(1)+{\rm r}(A-\mathbb{I}_3)=3$$

implying that the rank of the $A-\mathbb{I}_3$ is $1$. Now on to find $\mathcal{V}(1)$. In order to do so we have to solve the system $(A-\mathbb{I}_3)X=0$ which is easily reduced down to the system:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
kx+y &=0 \\ 
 mx+ ny&=0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And I got stuck at this point. I don't get enough equations so that I can actually determine the values of the parameters. Any help?

Comment: "determine the parameters" means "find necessary and sufficient conditions on the parameters".

Comment: So, you imply that that we cannot determine them? Strange, since the exercise in continuity asks me to find the inverse matrix of $A$.

Comment: You have to know the numerical value of every entry in a matrix, in order to find the inverse of the matrix? You can't find the inverse of, say, $$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}$$ if I tell you that $ad-bc\ne0$?

Comment: Yeah, I can find the inverse of the matrix you give. That is easy. So, you say we cannot find them. Hmm... then what are the conditions ? Are the conditions I wrote enough?

Comment: you don't actually need to solve that system. you only need it's rank

Comment: @user251257 But the rank is one. We know that from the equation I stated above.

Comment: it is at least $1$, isn't it

Comment: You want your system to have a nontrivial solution, right? And that gives you a condition on $k,m,n$, right? And that's all you need, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes... thank you.

Comment: Good. Now, I encourage you to write out and post an answer, based on what you now understand (the software may make you wait a while to do this).

Comment: That a matrix is diagonalizable is a stronger requirement than being invertible. A matrix can have full rank and not be diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system of equations that define the kernel of $A-I$ must have rank $1$ for $\ker A-I$ to have dimension 2, because of the *rank-nullity theorem*. This means the condition is  the vectors $(k,1)$ and $(m,n)$ must be colinear. Explicitly:
$$kn=m.$$

You should be able to check that, given that relation, the *minimal polynomial* of $A$ is $(x-1)(x-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

What is important is that when looking for eigenvectors for the $l=1$ eigenvalue, the equation system is not degenerate. If it is degenerate means that at least one vector is not a true eigenvector but is a *generalized eigenvector* residing in the same *generalized eigenspace* as the true one. And then diagonalization is not possible.

The necessary and sufficient condition is thus that your last equation system be not degenerate. row1: $[k,1]$ can not be allowed to be a scalar multiple of $[m,n]$

row operation removing $n$ times first row from second row gives $[m-nk,0]$.

So the requirement is $m-nk \neq 0$